# RegEx in Notepad++ - How to get specific line segments in repeating code blocks looking like this?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a lot of elements in a file, all looking somewhat like this:

```
class Item33
{
    position[]={3669.2529,10.441362,13108.502};
    name="car1";
    type="c_car";
    colorName="ColorWhite";
};
```

(This is an SQM file, no commonly known language though it might look similar to C++ or JS)

There might be one or two more or less lines, but that shouldn't matter as all I want is the numbers in the curly brackets which are coordinates in form {x,z,y} - don't ask me who put the z in the middle...

Actually, I know the *x and y coordinate* in ***square brackets***, so, for this example, the output I need is this:

```
[3669.2529,13108.502]
```

I'd be very glad if someone could manage that as it save me days of redundant work.

Kind regards,
stacky

Comment: Yes, like I wrote: [x, y]. Thanks.

Comment: did you wanna js solution?

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: So did you want to replace the remainder of the content between `class` and `}` ?

Comment: @hwnd, Either that or being able to copy all resulting arrays to clipboard (preferably with line break, but that's of lower importance).

Comment: @AvinashRaj, no, see previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression ...

```
Find: \bclass(?:[^{]*\{){2}([^,}]+),(?1),((?1))[^"]*("[^"]+")[^}]*\};
Replace: \3 [\1,\2]
```

Comment: If it's no big effort, could you please alter it in a way that it puts the string of the `name` line right before or after that array? Would be marvelous!

Comment: Is it possible to remove the line break? (Sorry, getting nitpicky here...)

Comment: Oh, lol, shame on me for not seeing the `\n` there. ^_^ Thank you very much for your help! As I cannot give your answer another thumb up, I'll tick your comment if you don't mind. Best regards, stacky